# What's wrong with my Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, testing

I would like regex to match if and only if the string is **none**, **family** or **work** (but not **my family**, for example).

Why the following code results with "match" ? Why **^** and **$** do not work ?

```
var regex = new RegExp("^none|family|work$");
var str = "my family";
document.write(regex.test(str) ? "match" : "no");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `|` operator has low precedence, so you effectively have `(^none)|(family)|(work$)`, which matches anything beginning with `none`, containing `family` or ending with `work`.

Use this instead:

```
^(none|family|work)$
```

Answer (score 4):

Your regex matches *either*:

- “none” at the beginning of the string;
- “family” anywhere in the string; *or*
- “work” at the end of the string.

What you probably want instead is

```
var regex = new RegExp("^(none|family|work)$");
```